# Boostrap licensing

Tags: internet, licensing

I try to understand [thoses licenses' differences](https://themes.getbootstrap.com/licenses/).

If I build a website that allows users to browse and book a city trip, would the Standard License be enough ?

I've read it a dozen times and I feel like its incoherent from a paragraph to another.

> Examples of Standard License Use:
>
> - A marketing site
>   for **a paid application** (where the Theme and it’s components are used
>   only on the marketing pages)

> The Full Standard License - Basics
>
> - You are licensed to use the Item to create one End Product for yourself or for
>   one client (a “single application”), and **the End Product can be
>   distributed for Free**.
> - Make unlimited copies of the single End Product **as long as the End Product
>   is distributed for free**
> - You cannot sell the End Product **except to one client**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While I agree that the license required for your use case isn't particularly obvious to me, the page you have linked to includes the following paragraph:

> Need help picking your license?
> Just shoot us an email at themes@getbootstrap.com and we’ll help you decide which license makes sense for your needs!

So in this case, my recommendation would be to get in touch as described, that way you will know for sure that you are properly licensed.

Comment: Thanks; I somehow missed that bit. I have now contacted them!